# Create ticket via ZendeskApi_v2

Tags: c#, api, zendesk

I am using the ZendeskApi_v2 nuget package, which is a NET Client Library by Elizabeth Schneider. I have managed to set up a connection and retrieve tickets from my account etc and display these in my webpage.

I am wondering how to use this API to create tickets. So far I have tried this approach:

[image]

However, this gives me an error.

Comment: What error does it give you?